# s6 slideshow internal links not working

Tags: jquery, slideshow, s5

### Internal links not working in S6 Slideshow

I'm trying to add navigational links - ie links between slideshow pages.
This works fine in Eric Meyer's S5 but it doesn't work in the jquery supported S6 format.
The correct href appears in the browser address box after clicking the link. But to make it work you have to then click refresh.

link example:

```
 <a href="#5">Click here for Slide 5</a>
```

Something (some jquery?) is stopping the default behaviour of the link. I have searched the scripts (mainly jquery.slideshow.js) for "return false" and found only one - this was to add the behaviour of clicking on the titles of the slides to advance the slide. I tried changing the "return false" to "return true" (a guess) but this didn't work. I also searched for "preventDefault" but there weren't any.

Does anyone know where the links are being disabled in the S6 scripts?

I am sure I could add some script to refresh the whole thing. I tried location.reload(false) but it insists on reloading from the server which defies the point of having all the pages locally cached. And anyway, I am trying to get to know jquery and I its getting to me that I can't find out why these links have been disabled.